# How do i write php variable in html apdiv?

Tags: php, html

i want to make a link for edit page but in the html div. when i click edit it should bring me to the edit page but the book_ID can't be read?

```
<div id="apDiv8">
    
     <!--list book table here-->
     <table border="2" style="width:1049px">
    <tr>
         <td><div align="center"><b>Edit</b></div></td>
       <td><div align="center"><b>Delete</b></div></td>
       <td><div align="center"><b>Book ID</b></div></td>
       <td><div align="center"><b>Book Title</b></div></td>
       <td><div align="center"><b>Book Author Name</b></div></td>
       <td><div align="center"><b>Book Count Page</b></div></td>
       <td><div align="center"><b>Entry Date</b></div></td>
       <td><div align="center"><b>Book Type</b></div></td>
       <td><div align="center"><b>Book Publication Year</b></div></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
         <td><div align="center"><a href = "edit_book.php?id='.$row['book_ID'].'">Edit</a></div></td>
         <td><div align="center"><a href = "delete_book.php?id='.$row['book_ID'].'">Delete</a></div></td>
         <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row['book_ID']; ?></div></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['book_title']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['book_author']; ?></td>
         <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row['book_page']; ?></div></td>
         <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row['book_entryDate']; ?></div></td>
         <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row['book_type']; ?></div></td>
         <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row['book_year']; ?></div></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<?php echo` just like you do in the `<td>`.

```
         <td><div align="center"><a href = "edit_book.php?id=<?php echo $row['book_ID']; ?>">Edit</a></div></td>
         <td><div align="center"><a href = "delete_book.php?id=<?php echo $row['book_ID']; ?>">Delete</a></div></td>
```